# Securely store a password in the application in C#

Tags: c#, security, passwords

I created a program to import sensitive information in it.
To prevent **other people** from **accessing** the app, I need a password to log in to the app.

If I put the password in the string, it will be easy to see and there is **no security**.
I reviewed several sites but did not find a good answer.

What is the password protection method?

Thankful.

Comment: What’s your threat model here? Where is the app located? Who are the ‘other people’? Do they have access to the app, or the machine it is located on? Do they have admin privileges?

Comment: Oh, and what does “put the password in the string” mean? What string is this?

Comment: The program may be decompiled by hackers. This is an internal app. I want the password to be protected on the program itself or in another way.

Comment: It is impossible to keep secrets embedded in client applications completely secure.

Comment: I know there is no way for 100% security. But I don't want to easily find the password.

Comment: You can however keep the data the program uses secure by encrypting it with a password the user would need to enter into the app to unlock it. In this case, you don’t store the password at all, simply ask the user to enter it when you need to decrypt/encrypt their data.

Comment: But I need a login page. I need to have a way to protect my password with more percentages.

Comment: How do you store the sensitive information the user is entering into your application?

Comment: Are you trying to protect the user’s data or the entire program itself? (The latter is impossible)

Comment: There are some ways to encrypt this information. But even in this case, the Key, which is supposed to be used for encryption / decryption, should be kept safe?

Comment: My main problem is keeping Key in a safe place.

Comment: The safe place the key is kept is in the user’s brain. When your program needs the key to decrypt the data, it retrieves it from the user’s brain by displaying a login page.

Comment: This is a good way to solve my problem. But is there a way to store String and other data securely somewhere securely?

Comment: _The program may be decompiled by hackers. This is an internal app_ if you've got hackers inside your network, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: @stuartd One of my main problems is the decompiled by the hacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.7.2), it stores the underlying information encrypted in the memory. If you use WPF there is a control PasswordBox which also stores the password in a SecureString.

Answer (score 1):

The trend these days is to use 3rd party services such as Auth0 to handle authentication and authorization, that way passwords are never stored directly in the database of your application: https://auth0.com/

If you go the route of storing passwords in your own database the simplest approach is to hash the password going in the insert with a one-way hashing algorithm such as md5, SHA256, or Bcrypt. I don't know what libs are available in the C# ecosystem specifically but let's pretend you bring in one called `bcrypt` and assume you've instantiated it and all that. In your controller method you might see something like this:

```
var user = new User
    {
        name = input.name,
        password = bcrypt(input.password)
    };

_context.Add(user);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is a fairly primitive approach to storing passwords securely, but it's better than storing them in plain text. It's worth doing some more research into the topic of hashing and salting passwords if you care about security.

Either way, what happens here, is that the plain text password is sent through a one-way hash, meaning the encrypted text can't be reversed. This means your application never knows what a user's password actually is.

The way you authenticate a user is by comparing the hashed version of the password entered on sign-in against the password in the database (which went through the same hashing function). If the two strings match, the user entered the correct password.

Now, most applications usually have some sort of system admin user that needs to be set. The way I've handled this is by creating a seeder for my database that creates a user with credentials that I set up as environment variables in some config file, for example, a `.env`.

The `.env` might look something like:

```
ADMIN_USER_NAME=admin
ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD=password
```

The seeder would use those values and insert a user with whatever roles and permissions are required for a system admin.

The `.env` itself is never checked into version control and the production credentials only exist on the production environment (you would make dummy credentials in dev environments).

Assuming the seeder can only be run by someone with permission to access the production environment directly, this is a pretty secure way to set up the initial system admin user, whose password is also hashed just like any other user so you still don't have raw text credentials sitting your db in case of a breach.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is about how to hide the typed chars from being seen, just set the PasswordChar of the textfield to '*' as example.

Comment: I mean password protection. This means that the password can not be accessed with Decompiler programs. I do not mean hiding passwords.

Comment: OK, got it. Btw, I do not believe you will be able to store a password 100% secure inside source code..

Comment: Right. I'm aware of this. But I want to reduce the speed of it.